# Logging in the New Created User Ubuntu12.04 lts

Tags: login, login-screen, users, display-manager

I just created an account with name `rashmi` and set its password. Then I restarted my system. When I log in to `rashmi` another screen appears for less than a second and then vanish and again the login screen comes back. So I am not able to login in to Ubuntu from the newly created user

I created my user with `sudo useradd rashmi`, then set its password using `sudo passwd rashmi`.

Can anyone please tell me how to log in as a new user and where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By default useradd simply creates the user account and group in the /etc/passwd and /etc/group files. It does not create a home directory for the new user. Instead run the `sudo adduser username` command, which will prompt for extra information including password, full name, etc. and then create a home directory which will be populated from default information in /etc/skel.

To fix this, you have two options. The simplest would be to run `sudo userdel rashmi`, and then start again with the `adduser` command, or you could manually create the home directory as root user, and change the ownership of the copied files to match that of the new user:

```
ls /home/rashmi
```

Confirm that there is no data about to be overwritten. Then

```
sudo cp -a /etc/skel /home/rashmi
sudo chown -R rashmi:rashmi /home/rashmi
```

I recommend using the first method if possible, as it will add a usergroup for the new user, which you may not have done yet (you can do this manually by editing the /etc/group file as the root user).